# Plymouth falling back to text boot animation

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu, plymouth

Ever since a kernel update and reinstalling the `nvidia-346` package for the Nvidia proprietary drivers for my GPU, Plymouth has been reverting to using the text boot animation instead of the graphics one.

Log snippet using `plymouth.debug=file:/var/log/plymouth-debug.log`:

```
[ply-device-manager.c:303] create_seats_for_subsystem:found device /sys/devices/virtual/graphics/fbcon
[ply-device-manager.c:334] create_seats_for_subsystem:it's not initialized
[ply-device-manager.c:713] create_seats_from_udev:Creating non-graphical seat, since there's no suitable graphics hardware
```

My problem is pretty much summed up [here](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/plymouth/2014-June/000767.html).
I have manually added `70-uaccess.rules` `71-seat.rules` and `73-seat-late.rules` but still have the same problem.

This has worked before while using the drivers straight off Nvidia, so it might be with package dependencies and scripts of the `nvidia-346` package - who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after a (long) time I figured out the issue:

In `grub`, changing the config to include `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` and `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920X1080` seemed to solve my problem

I'm guessing here that `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` is what really makes a difference, as setting it to anything other than `keep` (e.g. a resolution like `1920x1080`) would give me the fallback text boot screen.